# deploying nodejs app with forever

Tags: port-forwarding, node.js

Hello I am trying my first deploy in my life on a 'production' server, and i have the following question: after setting everything up on the server, and run

```
npm start app.js
```

I can connect to the node server (I have redirected the requests from :80 to :3000)

But if I run it with

```
forever start app.js
```

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Do you have any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Because the app didn't start.

Comment: any ideas, someethign that would help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script is throwing an error, e.g. your port is in use - if you run

```
forever list
```

that will show you processes and their log files.  You can then open the file to view, e.g.

```
open /Users/<you>/.forever/<somefile>.log
```

before you restart, ensure you run 'stopall' first, so that ports aren't in use.

```
forever stopall
```